# How should I stop my craving for money and people?

Tags: craving

I have strong craving for money and people because I consider them basic for survival. But I know money is not going to stay with me forever and people are not going to stay with me forever. I have developed a fear of loosing people and money.

My question is : How should I stop my craving for money and people ?

Comment: Question is too broad. Please narrow it down by adding e.g. particular tradition or what kind of answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Donate as much as you can to counter your greed.
Do [Marananussati](https://dhammawiki.com/index.php/Marananussati) or [Patikulamanasikara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patikulamanasikara) or [Satipatthana](https://www.sirimangalo.org/text/how-to-meditate/) meditation to counter the craving towards people.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are tackling it off the wrong foot.

There isn't much merit in trying to cut off (or stop) the craving, for it only brings misery and great dissatisfaction of the *present moment*. The Buddhist way is keeping in mind the Right resolve while abandoning Wrong resolve, keeping in mind Right livelihood and abandoning Wrong livelihood, keeping in mind Right action and abandoning Wrong action. All of this **on case by case bases**, as you cannot magically grab a wand and get rid yourself of all the afflictions; attempt of doing it so drastically gives you only extent of self-mortification which Buddha disproved of.

Thinking about how joyful future would be if you didn't have a craving and affliction is not going to help you either, but make things much worse.  You are attaching yourself to immediate progress on the path, therefore it only brings suffering. Suffering due to longing for ending of craving brings self-loathing and inner critique. You will develop unhealthy obsession which is clinging. Let go of the obsession over future and tackle the present now; when the moment approaches keep mindfulness so that you act rightfully with generosity and plant the good seed in your mind. Planting good seeds will eventually transform your habits and afflictions as old seeds naturally wither.

As a side note, please watch Ajah Brahm's talk on Right livelihood; he says it is fine to be rich, but make money in the right way, with benefit to others, without attaching yourself to wealth too much, but treating the loss of it with wisdom. There is not much negative in wealth, but in unhealthy attachment to it, the same goes for people and self-appreciation they give. It is fine to have good company, but realise impermanence of such relationships.

---

*Addendum*.
The only way Buddhism ever worked for me personally is when I took Right effort to heart and adjusted my practise to be effortless and joyful journey. That is, I took my current level of advancement on the path and set realistic goals with boundaries that would make me practise comfortably. And then, after some time, with higher insight and realisation, I would readjust the boundary for my current level of practise, but all within the balance of comfort and effortlessness. Remind yourself of string analogy Buddha gave to Sona. After all, do you expect to become realised Arhat overnight? It takes **lifetimes** for laypeople to even get to moderate state of realisation, liberation and happiness. That keeping in mind that in Buddhism laypeople are of different capacity, each one has their unique way!

Comment: Nice answer but I am a complete Buddha fan. I do not believe in beating around the bush. Buddha clearly says intention of renunciation , intention of non-ill will,intention of non-cruelty are right intentions. Ultimately one has to renounce all the five aggregates as not me. Actually I should be enthusiastic about the renunciation but I am not, which shows I haven't understood Dhamma properly. Mindfulness helps everyone whether they renounce or not.

Comment: One does not need to do more than follow Eightfold path in Buddhism, cessation of craving is not to be understood on intellectual level and experienced by transformation of your habits with mindfulness, hence my answer. Intention of renunciation is in Right effort also, which is a way of adjusting your mind to achieve peace instead of torment, as practise has to be bringing joy and happiness. Why else would you practise? For which purpose if not cessation of affliction, which is here obsession, impatience and aversion? Buddhism itself is not a path of change, but liberation.

Comment: And yes, practise eventually brings change as a result of liberation from suffering and mental affliction, but change is not a goal of practise itself; in a way that the goal is not striving for change as such is just another reaffirmation of Self. We don't really have to rely on change to be happy here and now.

Answer (score 0):

Just consider this,
if you need money you have to be educated and must have a job, then of course you have to work. Woke up in the morning and get on vehicle go to work and work with pressure, come back home sleep and continue this loop for long time. If you get a loan then you have to save money rather spend it on other needs, now that's very painful.
craving for people, just think about your death, it is ultimate destiny of all people which we face alone. No one else cannot help or come with us.
( this is what I've learned from the society it may be defer to others, anyway i think this would be helpful).